# How can I sort individual words inside a list, using map() function?

Tags: python, sorting

I have a `list of words` that I am trying to `sort` within a list:

```
words = ["yo", "act", "flop",'tac']

words = list(map(sorted,words))


Desired outcome: ['oy','act','flop','act']
```

The above splits up each word inside words into individual characters- but does sort it:

1. why does it do this? Because we are just sorting?
2. how can I rejoin them so that they are words again rather than individual characters? I know it is using `"".join()`, but I can't seem to wrap this around the above!

Thanks!

Comment: Why are you using `map` in there? It's applying `sorted` to each element in the list individually. Just use `sorted(words)`

Comment: Ohh I see, I thought sorted() would just sort the words as they are but put them in alphabetical order as they currently sit. But it seems to work, so thanks

Comment: No it is wrong! simply doing sorted(words) does NOT work...

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`sorted` works on arbitrary iterable values, but *always* returns a list, not a value of the same iterable it just sorted.

```
>>> sorted("yo")
['o', 'y']
```

That means you have to take the sorted list and turn it back into a string yourself.

```
>>> [''.join(sorted(x)) for x in words]
['oy', 'act', 'flop', 'act']
```

You can still use `map`, but it's a little messier than just using a list comprehension:

```
>>> list(map(lambda x: ''.join(sorted(x)), words))
['oy', 'act', 'flop', 'act']
```

---

Because Python doesn't support function composition natively, you can't write something concise (and possibly more efficient) like

```
list(map(''.join ∘ sorted, words))
```

(where `∘` is a hypothetical operator that behaves like

```
(f ∘ g) == lambda x: f(g(x))
```

)

Composition always involves creating an additional function that needs to be called in order to call the original two functions, rather than creating a separate single function that does the same *thing* as the original two.

The other alternative (`list(map(''.join, map(sorted, words)))`) isn't much better; although `map(f∘g, x)` is generally equivalent in effect to `map(f, map(g, x))`, now you are iterating over the sequence twice (or rather, iterating over one sequence, then iterating over a second intermediate sequence).

Answer (score 0):

If it doesn't already have a name, you need to define the function that you want to map over the list.

You can define a function either with `def`, or with `lambda`.

```py
words = ["yo", "act", "flop",'tac']

def f(w):
  return ''.join(sorted(w))

print( list(map(f, words)) )
# ['oy', 'act', 'flop', 'act']

print( list(map(lambda w: ''.join(sorted(w)), words)) )
# ['oy', 'act', 'flop', 'act']
```

Answer (score 0):

You can also use join in the map function call:

```
words = list(map(lambda x: "".join(sorted(x)),words))
print(words)
>>> ['oy', 'act', 'flop', 'act']
```

Comment: areobe, is the reason we use lambda instead of just sorted inside map() so that we can incorporate "".join(...)?

Comment: @user15877202 we use lambda to define a function without a name. All lambda is doing is just creating a nameless function with one variable x. This function returns "".join(sorted(x)). Indeed we use lambda so we can incorporate the join in the map.